# issue returning data to activity from AsyncTask

Tags: java, android

I am having trouble getting data back from an asynctask in a separate class firle into my main activity.

Here is my main activity:

```
public class Main extends Activity {
EditText searchOne;
EditText searchTwo;

Button findMovies;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.totlayout);

    //set the UI elements
    searchOne = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.searchOne);
    searchTwo = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.searchTwo);

    findMovies = (Button) findViewById(R.id.findMovies);


}
public void displayResults(View view){
    //do something in response to button
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, DisplayResultsActivity.class);

    //make person search url1
    final StringBuilder personSearchURLOne = new StringBuilder(getName.getName1(searchOne)); 
    final String searchURLOne = personSearchURLOne.toString();
    Log.d("searchurlone", searchURLOne.toString());

    //make person search url2
    final StringBuilder personSearchURLTwo = new StringBuilder(getName.getName2(searchTwo));
    final String searchURLTwo = personSearchURLTwo.toString();

    //get ID 1 this needs to get data back from asynctask in the type string to be passed to buildCreditURL
    new getFirstID().execute(searchURLOne);

    //get ID 2
    new getFirstID().execute(searchURLTwo);

    //make credit search url1
    final StringBuilder creditURLOne = new StringBuilder(buildCreditURL.getCreditURLOne(firstID));
```

Here is my separate class file containing my AsyncTask:

```
package com.tot.tipofthetongue;

import android.os.AsyncTask;

import android.util.Log;





import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;

import org.json.JSONObject;

public class getFirstID extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

public static String TAG_ID = "id";
public static String TAG_RESULTS = "results";


String personOne = null;
static String firstID = null;


@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... personSearchURLOne) {
    Log.d("personSearchURLOne in getFirstID containts", personSearchURLOne[0]);

    JSONArray results = null;

    JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();

    JSONObject jSon = jParser.doInBackground(personSearchURLOne[0]);

    try{
        results = jSon.getJSONArray(TAG_RESULTS);

        for(int i = 0; i < results.length(); i++){
            JSONObject r = results.getJSONObject(i);
            firstID = r.getString(TAG_ID);

        }


    }
    catch(JSONException e){
        Log.e("Error", e.toString());
    }
            /need this value as string to be passed back to the main activity
    return firstID;


}




}
```

How do I firstID out as a string into my main activity to it can be used in another method belonging to another separate class file.

UPDATED getFirstID:

```
package com.tot.tipofthetongue;


import android.os.AsyncTask;

import android.util.Log;





import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;

import org.json.JSONObject;

 public class getFirstID extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

public static String TAG_ID = "id";
public static String TAG_RESULTS = "results";


String personOne = null;
static String firstID = null;


@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... personSearchURLOne) {

    Log.d("personSearchURLOne in getFirstID containts", personSearchURLOne[0]);

    JSONArray results = null;

    JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();

    JSONObject jSon = jParser.doInBackground(personSearchURLOne[0]);

    try{
        results = jSon.getJSONArray(TAG_RESULTS);

        for(int i = 0; i < results.length(); i++){
            JSONObject r = results.getJSONObject(i);
            firstID = r.getString(TAG_ID);

        }


    }
    catch(JSONException e){
        Log.e("Error", e.toString());
    }
    return firstID;


}
@Override
public void onPostExecute(String firstID){

}




}
```

Answer (score 2):

Override the method `onPostExecute(String result)` in your `getFirstID` class:

```
@Override protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
    // Invoke method on Main activity or do other action.
}
```

This method is executed by the UI thread and can update the view. You can add a reference to the `MainActivity` by setting it in a field of the `getFirstID` class by passing it in the constructor.

Hope it helps!

Comment: I added the @Override in my update but I am not sure how invoke it on the main thread and get my value out. I am very new to this. Can you elaborate?

Answer (score 2):

A Very Simple way would be to do this.

```
public class getFirstID extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Pair<String, String>> {
    public static interface MyAsyncCallback {
        /**
         * Called when the AsyncTask is finished processing the url.
         * @param url the url that the firstId was from
         * @param firstId the id that was parsed out of the json object
         */
        public void setFirstId(String url, String firstId);
    }

    private final MyAsyncCallback mCallback;

    public getFirstID(MyAsyncCallback callback) {
       mCallback = callback;
    }

   public Pair<String,String> doInBackground(String... params) {
       String firstID = parseJsonForID(params); // I am not going to copy your alg into here.
       return Pair.create(params[0], firstId);
   }


   public void onPostExecute(Pair<String,String> urlAndFirstId) {
     mCallback.setFirstId(urlAndFirstId.first, urlAndFirstId.second);
   }
}

public class Main extends Activity implements MyAsyncCallback {
  ....

 public void setFirstId(String url, String firstID) {
      // Example
      Intent intent = new Intent(this, OtherActivity.class);
      intent.putExtra("firstId", firstId);
      intent.putExtra("url", url);
      startActivity(intent);
 }
}
```

Comment: In Activity, once AsyncTask is started, how do you know exactly when AsyncTask is finished and FirstID is properly set at coding time? The problem is you can't predict when FirstID is ready as it is running separate thread and determined at application run time. without using some wait mechanium for instance AsyncTask.get(); the callback implementation is meaningless.

Comment: No the callback is not meaningless. The String passed in the callback, is the value. It is ready to be used. So the first ID is the string that was found. Treat everything in the callback method of setFirstId(String firstId); to be what you would do once you have the id and the task is for sure finished. There is no wait.

Comment: I updated the code so that the callback now manages the pairing of the URl that the firstId. So when the callback event happens, you know that the id came from the given url.

Comment: I am confused at what you are arguing? What is done with the `firstID` instance variable is not known to me, especially given the question. It might just need to be displayed, which is certainly not be done in the background. This code simply calls back into the Activity to tell it, the information it requested received and parsed in a background task, be returned to it when finished.

Comment: I need to pass firstID to a method in another class that constructs a url that contains the string value of the id.

Comment: So the rest of the thing is up to your application design, which is sounding questionable, since you have two async tasks firing simultaneously on sep data. I can see that you want 2 pieces of data processed, and one activity to handle the outcome of both (simultaneously?). I have updated the code with a sample callback impl. If you want simultaneous updates, then when you call asyncTask.execute() pass both urls to one call (it's a varg) and do one asyncTask and consolidate the results. You may want to update your question or ask the second part of your question, as a separate question.

Answer (score 1):

You can send stuff to another activity by using intent.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, YourActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("name", string);
```

Read about it [here](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity.html)

Or you could just put your AsyncTask class inside your activity class.

```
public class Main extends Activity {

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.get_data);


}

private class Download extends AsyncTask <Void, Void, String> {

    protected String doInBackground(Void...params) {

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {

    }

}

}
```

Comment: so in my getFirstID class when I add: Inent intent = new Intent(this, Main.class); under doInBackground I get a constructor undefined error.